# The tooltip over my reputation score value shows the reputation score value

Tags: feature-request, reputation, tooltips

Just discoved this:

[image]

*(Tooltip showing the exact value as already shown)*

This just made me think:

[image]

**Question:**

Isn't the tooltip showing redundant information?

Comment: Suppose a new user see the top bar. He see "1". He has no idea what it means so he hover. "Ah, this is my reputation. Cool!"

Comment: Thanks, guys. Following the idea of @ShadowWizard, one could argue to give _everything_ a tooltip (including e.g. the logo image on the site - "I see a logo ... what's that? ... <hovers> ... "Logo" ... oh hey, this is a logo, cool...")

Comment: @UweKeim actually many of the stuff got a tooltip already and `alt` is a required HTML attribute for images to give alternative text when the image isn't available or for screen readers. So yes, even site logo should have alt text saying "site logo".

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian true, but I doubt SE will implement custom tooltip. It means lots of client side code running for little gain. Also faster title might upset users who are used to the generic tooltip of browsers.